# WooCommerce Subscriptions create order without trial period

Tags: php, woocommerce

I have a WooCommerce product which is setup as a monthly subscription. It has a 7 days trial. I want to create a subscription for a user but without the trial period. I have tried it using the following code but it seems to be adding the trial period as well and the cost is set to zero which should be paying for the first month of the subscription;

```
$product = wc_get_product($productid);
        $quantity = 1;
        $order = wc_create_order(array('customer_id' => $userid));

        $order->add_product( $product, $quantity, array());
        $order->set_address( $address, 'billing' );
        $order->set_address( $address, 'shipping' );

        $period = WC_Subscriptions_Product::get_period($product);
        //$trial_end = date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime( $start_date." + ".$product->subscription_trial_length." ".$product->subscription_trial_period."s" ) );//WC_Subscriptions_Product::get_trial_expiration_date( $product->ID );
        $interval = WC_Subscriptions_Product::get_interval($product);
        $sub = wcs_create_subscription(array(
            'order_id' => $order->id,
            'billing_period' => $period,
            'billing_interval' => $interval,
            'start_date' => $start_date,
            'customer_id' => $userid
        ));
        $sub->add_product($product, $quantity, array());
        $sub->set_address($address, 'billing');
        $sub->set_address($address, 'shipping');
        $dates = array (
            'trial_end' => $wc_subscription->get_date( "trial_end"),
            'next_payment' => $start_date,
            'end' => date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime( $start_date." + ".$product->subscription_length." ".$product->subscription_period."s" ) ),
        );
        $sub->update_dates($dates);
        $sub->update_status("on-hold", "Created after the last subscription expiration!");
        $sub->calculate_totals();
        $sub->delete_date( 'trial_end' );
```

Answer (score -1):

You can set trial period to 0 days in the product data section of product overview

Comment: Please elaborate on this answer, as it's very minimalistic. You should add either a code example or a better explanation to your answer. For reference, read [answer] to see how you should answer questions.

Comment: There's no need to elaborate? And there's no code needed.. "You can set the trial period to 0 days / eliminate trial period, in the product data section of product overview, located in the woocommerce > products section of wordpress platform"

Comment: I think he was trying to enable/disable the trial as an option during checkout for specific users or conditions, not 'all the times' (thru the options)... maybe something like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53359221/setting-free-trial-programatically-for-a-cart-item-in-woocommerce-subscriptions