# Setting free trial programatically for a cart item in WooCommerce Subscriptions

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, subscription

I'm trying to set the free trial period of a cart item in WooCommerce during an add to cart AJAX request. The code seems to work when there is one subscription product in the cart, but when there are two or more of the same subscription product in the cart, the free trial is applied to all those products as well, even though the code is only specifically altering the cart data for one of the products. The code I'm using is below. Also $job->get_free_trial_length() is definitely returning the correct value. Any help would be greatly appreciated as I've been struggling with this for some time! Thanks.

UPDATE

When changing the free trial period on the cart item, it seems to also updates the subscription product's free trial period, which is why the other products also changed. So my question is, can free trials be done on a cart item level instead of a product level?

```
/**
* Add the subscription package to the user's cart.
*
* @param int $job_id
* @param int $variation_id
* @return string
*/
function add_package_to_cart( $job_id, $variation_id ) {

    $job        = fcrm_get_job( $job_id );
    $product_id = $job->get_linked_subscription_product_id();
    $quantity   = 1;

    $cart_item_data = array(
        'job_id' => $job_id
    );

    // Add to cart
    $key = WC()->cart->add_to_cart( $product_id, $quantity, $variation_id, array(), $cart_item_data );

    // Set the free trial period
    wcs_set_objects_property( WC()->cart->cart_contents[ $key ]['data'], 'subscription_trial_length', $job->get_free_trial_length() );

    return $key;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution. wcs_set_objects_property() accepts a 4th argument to not save the value to the database, but instead keep the value in memory. Then call the function every time cart totals are calculated.

Comment: I'm trying to do a similar thing and am having the same problem you had, I think: if I set the property to a new value *without* the $save parameter, it updates the product itself, not the cart item. But if I set that fourth item to, e.g. 'set_prop_only', then it seems to have NO effect at all, i.e. totals in the cart don't reflect the revised trial length. Is the code above your final working code, and if not, would you mind sharing the final code? Thanks! (([related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58037320/woocommerce-subscriptions-set-subscription-trial-length-per-cart-item))

Answer (score 0):

The `wcs_set_objects_property` function is deprecated now, so the more modern approach would be to use `WC()->cart->cart_contents[ $key ]['data']->update_meta_data( 'subscription_trial_length' $job->get_free_trial_length() );`, which is working as expected.